# Regex matches inside matches (match comments inside STYLE tags)

Tags: php, regex

## Matching comments inside STYLE tags with single regex

How to find matches inside the matched pattern `a <style>several matches here</style> and <style>here too</style>`?

Example:

```
/*0*/ <style>/* 1 */ 2 /**3***/4*//*
5/*6*/</style> 7/*8 <style>9*//*10*/</style>/*11*/</style>
```

Expected matches:

**`/* 1 */`, `/**3***/`, `/*
5/*6*/`, `/*10*/`**

Regex `/\/\*.*?\*\/(?=.*?<\/style>)/gs` https://regex101.com/r/Nm7joV/3 matches also outside STYLE tags.

**Update:** The benefit if single regex can manage cases where STYLE tag is in comment like `...<style>.../* match </style> till here*/</style>...`.

Comment: What if you have `/*</style>*/` between `<style>` and `</style>`? Don't parse this with regex. Better use a `DOM`

Comment: @anubhava I thought about such case before. Anyway question isn't about that case. If single regex can fix it too, it would be only a benefit.

Comment: You can't do this by a regex because the limiters are so much complex. If it's a `DOM` use a `DOM` parser. If it's only a kind of markup text, create your own parser.

Comment: @GabrielHeming, I manage to do it with single regex, see my answer. ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can do it with https://regex101.com/r/Nm7joV/9

```
(?=<style>)|\G(?!\A)(?!</style>).*?\K(?s)/\*.*?\*/
```

It covers also cases when STYLE tag is in comment, like

```
/*0*/ <style>/* 1 <style>*/ 2 /**3</style>***/4*//*
5/*6*/</style> 7/*8 <style>9*//*10*/</style>/*11*/</style>
```

matches:

**`/* 1 <style>*/`, `/**3</style>***/`, `/*
5/*6*/`, `/*10*/`**